# Why won't my Javascript/ Jquery code work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle which can be seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/pg3n9/2/

When you use it, you will see that my scroll functions work fine, but when I try to implement it with my real code, none of my scroll links work!?!

This is my html/css/javascript code that I need help on, if you would be able to help in any way, that would be great ! I apologize if there are similar questions out there, I would just love to know what I am doing wrong when implementing my javascript with my html

Rowan,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Tongue n Cheek </title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="cbp-fbscroller" class="cbp-fbscroller">

    <section id="fbsection1"><section class="topheader">
    <div class="navigation">
        <a class="menu_link"href="#fbsection2"> scroll down </a>
        <a id="email" href="mailto:contact@tongue-n-cheek.com.au?Subject:Message%20From%20Your%20Website">Email</a>
        <a id="soundcloud" href="https://soundcloud.com/tongue-n-cheek" target="_blank">Sound Cloud </a>
        <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/tonguencheekofficial" target="_blank" alt="facebook"> Facebook </a>


        </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="fbsection2" name="fbsection2" alt="section2">

    </div>

     </section>
    <section id="fbsection3" name="fbsection3" alt="section3">
    </section>
    </body>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, 
.container,
.cbp-fbscroller,
.cbp-fbscroller section { 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}


/* The nav is fixed on the right side  and we center it by translating it 50% 
(we don't know it's height so we can't use the negative margin trick) */


/* background-attachment does the trick */
.cbp-fbscroller section {
    position: relative;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.no-touch .cbp-fbscroller section {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#fbsection1 {
    background:url(img/top.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;

}

#fbsection2 {
    background:white;
    height:100%;
}

#fbsection3 {
    background:#1c1c1c;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body{ background:#1c1c1c;
}
input[type=submit] {
    /* Size and position */
    width: 50%;
    margin-top:50%;
    float:right;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    position:center;

    /* Styles */
    background: #3487FF;    

    border: 1px solid #4e3043;

    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    /* Font styles */
    color: white;
    margin-right:25%;
    font-size: 16px;

    font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

email , a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:0;
    top:0px;
    z-index:10;
    font-family:'Raleway', Helvetica;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    transition:0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    -moz-transition:0.3s;
    -o-transition:0.3s;
    margin-right:35px;
}
a:hover { 
    opacity:0.75; 

}
#text {
    float:right;
    font-family:'Raleway', Helvetica;
    color:black;
    font-size:26px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.menu_link').bind('click',function(event){

        var $anchor = $(this);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 60
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo', function() {

            window.location.hash = $anchor.html();

        });

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});



</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you check your console for any error!

Comment: Are you opening this document on your pc  (i.e. HTML pages you load directly from disk to your browser)? if so, you are missing the `Http:` on your jquery library..

Comment: I just tried adding the http: - it was a great tip, however it did not solve the issue, but thankyou, that is definitely a great find !

Comment: look for console errors and add some console.log into your code to see where you're stuck.

Comment: Is this just a typo?

<link rel="stylsheet" ...

Comment: the stylesheet isn't currenlty in use, but thankyou for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `div` container in which to scroll your text. I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg3n9/3/)

proper way to calcolate the scrollTop value:

```
scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('name')).offset().top - $('#container').offset().top + $('#container').scrollTop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the jQuery UI

Here is an example of your code working: http://jsfiddle.net/acidrat/yGxhc/1/

So just include this in your  section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Look in the jsFiddle Toolbar on the left "Frameworks & Extensions" and you can see that i had to enable jquery ui

Comment: Thankyou very much, when I add that framework, It still doesn't seem to work, any further suggestions  ?

Comment: Is it much different from the jsfiddle example i posted above? You could try to put the relevant parts of your code to jsfiddle and i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the protocol-relative URL if you are viewing the site on your PC using file:// protocol because that's the protocol the browser will use for jQuery too and therefore cannot find. Using http should fix your problem. And, also include jQueryUI for the easeIn effect that you are using. That's it!

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Read up on http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/ if you want to know more on protocol-relative URLs